# How do add delay time in (jquery) ascensor.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ascensor

How do i add 'delay' option to move to next slide after clicking? Anyone tried?

Below is the plugin website.

```
https://github.com/seekvence/ascensor
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out setTimeout(), delay() functions

Answer (score 2):

read the documentation.

options for you i guess:

```
{
duration: 500,
easing: 4000
}
```

Comment: thanks. i tried http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/ "easeInQuint" and it works good :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the click event and use jQuery delay();